# Empty Recycle Bin error “Cannot Delete Dc100: Access denied.”

Tags: windows-xp

There are a number of answers to this question, none of which I have tried worked. I know exactly where this folder is but I can't delete it. I have booted into 'safe mode' with command prompt. Used 'cd' and the 'tab' key to find the actual directory 'Dc100'. Tried using the 'rd' command and still get the 'Access denied' error. Anybody got some different ideas on how to delete this directory?

Comment: First of, if you could link at least one of the answers you refer to in your question, that would be great (as then we could know what you may have tried). Second, have you got full rights on that folder?

Comment: Can you see what the permissions for that directory are?

Comment: I actually used a search on the error, so there are numerous sites that I tried that had answers. When I started to ask the question here I got an list of similar questions that had been asked before, I followed up on those.

Comment: Don't know what the permissions are, the folder/directory can't be seen using windows explorer. The only way you can find it is as set out in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried *other solutions* and did not work, I would advise you to use a Linux [**live-cd**](http://www.linux-live.org/) distribution and remove the file through there.